# Excel Macro VBA to search certain string

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Hey Experts out there,

I need your help. I have one excel workbook, start with master list, then list A, list B, and so on.
Master list has all the info, whereas list A, B and so on are the filtered excel files (filtered data from master list).

Now, i want to do is as below:
Find column I of each list whether it has "ABC" for example, if not then pop up msg box. If yes, continue to search for other strings.

Problem: The list A does not start with item 1(as it is filtered version).

Any way to do this? I hope can write it in Macro VBA.

Please help, give me ideas or give me any example links for reference.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your question.

1. Search a fulltext "ABC" in column I.

   ```
   Dim curCell as range
   Dim curSheet as worksheet
   For curSheet in WorkBook.Sheets
       For curCell in RANGE("I:I")
           If curCell.Text="ABC" Then
               MsgBox "hooo!"
           Endif
       Next
   Next
   ```
2. Search a substring "ABC" in column I's any Cell.

   ```
   Dim curCell as range
   Dim curSheet as worksheet
   For curSheet in WorkBook.Sheets
       For curCell in RANGE("I:I")
           If InStr(curCell.Text,"ABC")>0 Then
               MsgBox "hooo!"
           Endif
       Next
   Next
   ```

Comment: Thanks for yr answer. What i mean is master list we have 1 - 10, A: 1,2,3, B: 2,3,4 since they are filtered. How can i loop column "I" for each row for that list, like A we should loop 1, 2, 3 and B is 2, 3 4.